# npm failing building reactjs app

Tags: reactjs, npm

I am trying to write my first npm package (a hello world-like reactjs component) and I am fighting with webpack and npm configuration files on both ends: the new package and the main app.

After several hours and many trials I got the `npm start` for the package working in standalone my problem now is to be possible to install in the main app and compile+start with no errors.

Right now, my error is after `npm run compile`:`Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'twist-card-component' in <several wrong directories>` The right place should be `<package-dir>/dist/index.js` where index.js is the bundle file created after the `npm run build && npm pack` on the package creation.

### Files in the twist-card-component

**webpack.config.js**

```
/* jshint node: true */
var path = require('path');
module.exports = {
  context: path.join(__dirname),
   entry: './lib/index.js',

   output: {
path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
filename: 'index.js',
libraryTarget: 'umd',
library: 'TwistCardComponent'
},
module: {
loaders: [
  {
    test: /\.scss$/,
    // Query parameters are passed to node-sass
    loader: 'style!css!sass?outputStyle=expanded&' +
      'includePaths[]=' + (path.resolve(__dirname, './bower_components')) + 
'&' +
      'includePaths[]=' + (path.resolve(__dirname, './node_modules'))
  },
  {
    test: /(\.js)|(\.jsx)$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    loader: 'babel-loader',
    query: {
      optional: ['runtime'],
      stage: 0
    }
  }
]
}
};
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "twist-card-component",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "twist card component",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "eslint lib/ spec/ && ./node_modules/karma/bin/karma start karma.conf.js",
    "watch-test": "./node_modules/karma/bin/karma start karma.conf.js --auto-watch --no-single-run",
    "build": "webpack -p --display-error-details --colors",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --inline --hot"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "BSD",
  "keywords": [
    "react",
    "reactjs",
    "react-component"
  ],
  "files":["dist"],
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "~5.8.22",
    "babel-eslint": "^4.0.10",
    "babel-loader": "~5.3.2",
    "css-loader": "~0.16.0",
    "es5-shim": "~4.1.10",
    "eslint": "^0.21.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^2.3.0",
    "jasmine": "~2.3.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.3.4",
    "karma": "^1.7.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^0.3.8",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^0.2.3",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
    "karma-webpack": "^2.0.4",
    "node-sass": "^3.13.1",
    "phantomjs": "^2.1.7",
    "phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.15",
    "react": "^15.6.1",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "^15.6.0",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.1",
    "sass-loader": "~2.0.1",
    "sourcemap": "^0.1.0",
    "style-loader": "~0.12.3",
    "webpack": "^1.15.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "~1.10.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-runtime": "~5.8.20"
  }
}
```

### Main app

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "tracker-dashboard",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --hot",
    "compile": "webpack --colors --progress --display-error-details",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "ajv": "^5.2.2",
    "babel-core": "^6.25.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-preset-latest": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.4",
    "file-loader": "^0.11.2",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.3",
    "react": "^15.6.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.31.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.1.2",
    "reflux": "^6.4.1",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
    "style-loader": "^0.18.2",
    "twist-card-component": "file:../twist-card-component/twist-card-component-1.0.0.tgz",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.9"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "webpack": "^3.5.2",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.12.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.7.1"
  }
}
```

**webpack.config.json**

```
const path = require('path');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  context: path.join(__dirname, 'js'),
  entry: [
    './index.js',
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'www'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
    module: {

        loaders: [
            { test: /\.js$/, loader: 'babel-loader', exclude: /node_modules/  },
            { test: /\.css$/, loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract(
                {
                    fallback: "style-loader",
                    use: "css-loader?modules=true&camelCase=true"
                }
            )},
            {
                test: /\.(?:png|jpg|svg)$/,
                loader: 'url-loader',
                query: {
                    // Inline images smaller than 10kb as data URIs
                    limit: 10000
                }
            }

        ]

    },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
    modules: [
      path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules'),
    ],
  },
    plugins: [

        new ExtractTextPlugin({
            filename: "bundle.css?[hash]-[chunkhash]-[contenthash]-[name]",
            disable: false,
            allChunks: true
        })
    ],
    devServer: {
        port:3000,
        contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'www'),
    }
};
```

### npm run compile output

```
ERROR in ./components/panel/Panel.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'twist-card-component' in '/<path>/tracker-dashboard/js/components/panel'
resolve 'twist-card-component' in '/<path>/tracker-dashboard/js/components/panel'
  Parsed request is a module
  using description file: /<path>/tracker-dashboard/package.json (relative path: ./js/components/panel)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
  after using description file: /<path>/tracker-dashboard/package.json (relative path: ./js/components/panel)
    resolve as module
      looking for modules in /<path>/tracker-dashboard/node_modules
        using description file: /<path>/tracker-dashboard/package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        after using description file: /<path>/tracker-dashboard/package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
          using description file: /<path>/tracker-dashboard/node_modules/twist-card-component/package.json (relative path: .)
            no extension
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /<path>/tracker-dashboard/node_modules/twist-card-component is not a file
            .js
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /<path>/tracker-dashboard/node_modules/twist-card-component.js doesn't exist
            .jsx
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /<path>/tracker-dashboard/node_modules/twist-card-component.jsx doesn't exist
            as directory
              existing directory
                using path: /<path>/tracker-dashboard/node_modules/twist-card-component/index
                  using description file: /<path>/tracker-dashboard/node_modules/twist-card-component/package.json (relative path: ./index)
                    no extension
                      Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                      /<path>/tracker-dashboard/node_modules/twist-card-component/index doesn't exist
                    .js
                      Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                      /<path>/tracker-dashboard/node_modules/twist-card-component/index.js doesn't exist
                    .jsx
                      Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                      /<path>/tracker-dashboard/node_modules/twist-card-component/index.jsx doesn't exist
[/<path>/tracker-dashboard/node_modules/twist-card-component]
[/<path>/tracker-dashboard/node_modules/twist-card-component.js]
[/<path>/tracker-dashboard/node_modules/twist-card-component.jsx]
[/<path>/tracker-dashboard/node_modules/twist-card-component/index]
[/<path>/tracker-dashboard/node_modules/twist-card-component/index.js]
[/<path>/tracker-dashboard/node_modules/twist-card-component/index.jsx]
 @ ./components/panel/Panel.js 27:26-57
 @ ./components/Main.js
 @ ./components/App.js
 @ ./index.js
 @ multi ./index.js
```

### SOLUTION

Just added a "main" key to the package.json

```
"main": "dist/index.js"
```

Comment: After you run `npm install` for your Main app, `twist-card-component` should be placed into `<package-dir>/node_modules` directory. Can you check if it is so?

Comment: In your Main app you also should require this package as `require('twist-card-component')`.

Comment: Yes! The directory is there, and the bundle file is inside the dist folder. I amv appending the compilation output so you can see the compilations is not looking the correct folder (node_modules/twist-card-components/dist/index.js

Comment: Ok! I manage to fix it. It was missing a directive "main": "dist/index.js" . Thx!